# Adding SubtitleUrl is killing my app(ANR)

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, http-live-streaming

Hi Guys this may sound a bit silly, But when i'm loading an hls stream url to android VideoView the player begins streaming video just fine, But when i add the subtitle url to same the app crashes when i seek, i lose complete control on the app and the video stream does not stop playing(i.e It keeps playing even in the background).

This is what i'm doing.(pls help me figure out what mistake im doing.Thanks in advance)

```
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mProfileUrl));
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    if (null != mSubtitleUrl && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        new AddSubTitleAsync().execute(mSubtitleUrl);
    } 
}



//***************************************************************************

class AddSubTitleAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // pd = ProgressDialog.show(mParentNotifier.getParentActivty(), "", "", false, false);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
        // if (pd != null && pd.isShowing())
        // pd.dismiss();

        if (null != inputStream) {
            mVideoView.addSubtitleSource(inputStream, MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/vtt", Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage()));
        }
        // mParentNotifier.enableMainMenuLayout(false);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        // mVideoView.start();
        if (mMovieStartPoint > 0) {
            Timer mTimer = new Timer();
            mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mVideoView.seekTo(mMovieStartPoint);
                    mVideoView.start();
                }
            }, 5000);

            // mVideoView.seekTo(15 * 60 * 1000);
            // mVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            HttpHandler http = new HttpHandler();
            inputStream = http.getContent(params[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

}
```